# Error on read_csv('file.csv') on osx

Tags: python-3.x

```
    tst = pd.read_csv('Users/me/Desktop/stuff/Et2Load.csv')
    print(tst.shape())
```

File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 358, in pandas.parser.TextReader.**cinit** (pandas/parser.c:3427)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 628, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:6861)
OSError: File b'Users/me/Desktop/stuff/Et2Load.csv' does not exist

I saved the file on excel like this :https://s2member.com/kb-article/how-do-i-save-the-importexport-csv-with-excel-on-mac-os-x/
I have access to the /stuff directory because i can open png file

Comment: What about `pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Desktop/stuff/Et2Load.csv')` so you specify the full path instead of relative?

Comment: Yes, I do not have the error anymore. I wonder how many time i look at it. Not sure how i can accept it?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it - it's an answer that's only really applicable to you, so won't be of use to future visitors. If I were you, I'd probably just delete it and not worry about it :)